# Unable to import Javascript source in Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, jekyll

I'd like to add follow buttons to my Jekyll blog, but Javascript doesn't work in my .md file.

What I'm trying to do is adding share-buttons.html to the _includes folder then reaching it from the about.md file, however, I can't see the effect of it.

Any help is much appreciated.

about.md:

```
---
layout: page
title: some title
permalink: "/about"
---

Some text.

{% include share-buttons.html %}
```

share-buttons.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5c52b8423fe35822">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please do not use addthis.com. It is a surveillance company that is all about profiling.**

If you nevertheless choose to do so... use only this code for your 'share-buttons.html' (so leave out the other HTML stuff):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5c52b8423fe35822">
```

A better solution would be to link manually to the sharer URL of the desired platforms without external resources. Your share-buttons.html should look something like the code below.

```css
#share-buttons {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
#share-buttons:after {content: ""; display: block; clear: both;}
#share-buttons > div {position: relative; text-align: left; height: 36px; width: 32px; float: left; text-align: center;}
#share-buttons > div > svg {height: 16px; fill: #d5d5d5; margin-top: 10px;}
#share-buttons > div:hover {cursor: pointer;}
#share-buttons > div.facebook:hover > svg {fill: #3B5998;}
#share-buttons > div.twitter:hover > svg {fill: #55ACEE;}
#share-buttons > div.linkedin:hover > svg {fill: #0077b5;}
#share-buttons > div.pinterest:hover > svg {fill: #CB2027;}
#share-buttons > div.gplus:hover > svg {fill: #dd4b39;}
#share-buttons > div.mail:hover > svg {fill: #7D7D7D;}
#share-buttons > div.instagram:hover > svg {fill: #C73B92;}
#share-buttons > div.facebook > svg {height: 18px; margin-top: 9px;}
#share-buttons > div.twitter > svg {height: 20px; margin-top: 8px;}
#share-buttons > div.linkedin > svg {height: 19px; margin-top: 7px;}
#share-buttons > div.pinterest > svg {height: 20px; margin-top: 9px;}
#share-buttons > div.gplus > svg {height: 17px; margin-top: 9px; position: relative; left: 1px;}
#share-buttons > div.mail > svg {height: 14px; margin-top: 11px;}
```

```html
<div id="share-buttons">
    <div class="facebook" title="Share this on Facebook" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}');"><svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1343 12v264h-157q-86 0-116 36t-30 108v189h293l-39 296h-254v759h-306v-759h-255v-296h255v-218q0-186 104-288.5t277-102.5q147 0 228 12z"/></svg></div>
    <div class="twitter" title="Share this on Twitter" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}');"><svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1684 408q-67 98-162 167 1 14 1 42 0 130-38 259.5t-115.5 248.5-184.5 210.5-258 146-323 54.5q-271 0-496-145 35 4 78 4 225 0 401-138-105-2-188-64.5t-114-159.5q33 5 61 5 43 0 85-11-112-23-185.5-111.5t-73.5-205.5v-4q68 38 146 41-66-44-105-115t-39-154q0-88 44-163 121 149 294.5 238.5t371.5 99.5q-8-38-8-74 0-134 94.5-228.5t228.5-94.5q140 0 236 102 109-21 205-78-37 115-142 178 93-10 186-50z"/></svg></div>
    <div class="linkedin" title="Share this on Linkedin" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}&title=&summary=&source=');"><svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M477 625v991h-330v-991h330zm21-306q1 73-50.5 122t-135.5 49h-2q-82 0-132-49t-50-122q0-74 51.5-122.5t134.5-48.5 133 48.5 51 122.5zm1166 729v568h-329v-530q0-105-40.5-164.5t-126.5-59.5q-63 0-105.5 34.5t-63.5 85.5q-11 30-11 81v553h-329q2-399 2-647t-1-296l-1-48h329v144h-2q20-32 41-56t56.5-52 87-43.5 114.5-15.5q171 0 275 113.5t104 332.5z"/></svg></div>
    <div class="gplus" title="Share this on Google Plus" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}');"><svg viewBox="0 0 2304 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1437 913q0 208-87 370.5t-248 254-369 91.5q-149 0-285-58t-234-156-156-234-58-285 58-285 156-234 234-156 285-58q286 0 491 192l-199 191q-117-113-292-113-123 0-227.5 62t-165.5 168.5-61 232.5 61 232.5 165.5 168.5 227.5 62q83 0 152.5-23t114.5-57.5 78.5-78.5 49-83 21.5-74h-416v-252h692q12 63 12 122zm867-122v210h-209v209h-210v-209h-209v-210h209v-209h210v209h209z"/></svg></div>
    <div class="mail" title="Share this through Email" onclick="window.open('mailto:?&body={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}');"><svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1792 710v794q0 66-47 113t-113 47h-1472q-66 0-113-47t-47-113v-794q44 49 101 87 362 246 497 345 57 42 92.5 65.5t94.5 48 110 24.5h2q51 0 110-24.5t94.5-48 92.5-65.5q170-123 498-345 57-39 100-87zm0-294q0 79-49 151t-122 123q-376 261-468 325-10 7-42.5 30.5t-54 38-52 32.5-57.5 27-50 9h-2q-23 0-50-9t-57.5-27-52-32.5-54-38-42.5-30.5q-91-64-262-182.5t-205-142.5q-62-42-117-115.5t-55-136.5q0-78 41.5-130t118.5-52h1472q65 0 112.5 47t47.5 113z"/></svg></div>
</div>
```

You might want to remove Google Plus. ;-)

Source: https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/share-buttons/

Comment: I should've figured this out about AddThis. Thank you!